# Subtract elements from string till none in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to subtract first element from the string `s1 = 'asasas'` continuously,
till at the final step, `s1 = ''` is recieved.

I hope to find a code of the form:

```
s1 = s1 - s1[0]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Do you want to do anything with the first letter? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing in a loop.

```
s1 = 'asasas'
for i in range(len(s1)):
    print s1[i:]
```

Output

```
asasas
sasas
asas
sas
as
s
```

Answer (score 0):

A deque from the collections module may be useful.

"Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction."

Your code would be:

```
a = 'adsfasdfasdfasdfasdf'
import collections
s = collections.deque(a)
while len(s):
    c = s.popleft()
    print (s)
```